# Firing Projectiles in the same direction as my character is looking. [UNITY 2D TOPDOWN]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, unity3d-2dtools, topdown

I've searched through a bunch of posts on Top Down 2D rotation with firing missiles and none of them apply to mine.

My Wizard manages to fire his magicmissiles from his wand but they come out unaligned with his wands direction. [image: Examples] It should be taking the Z value from the Quaternion of the wand and assigning that as the angle it goes out in ( or atleast thats what i believe it should be doing) But it seems to rotate faster than the wand and whilst it does change if I spin it isn't changing equally with the wand. So whilst if I point up it will fire up. If i point 45 degrees right of that it fires the missile directly into my wizard.

The Code for the MissileMovement ---------------

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MoveMissile : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization

public float speed = 0.5F;
public Transform Shotspawn;
// public Quaternion Direction;
private float Direction;
void Start (){

    // Sets the direction that shot is fired in.
    Direction = transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z;
    transform.Rotate(0 , 0, Direction);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {


    transform.Translate(Vector2.up * speed);
 }
}
```

The Code for the Character Movement ---------------------------

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

 public class TopDownCharController2 : MonoBehaviour {

 // Movement Variables
 public float walkSpeed;
 public bool colliding; 

 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {

 }



 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update ()
 {

         if(Input.GetKey (KeyCode.I)) 
         {transform.Translate(Vector2.up * walkSpeed); } // UP MOVEMENT

         if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.J)) 
         {transform.Translate(-Vector2.right * walkSpeed); } // LEFT MOVEMENT

         if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.K)) 
         {transform.Translate(-Vector2.up * walkSpeed); }// DOWN MOVEMENT

         if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.L)) 
         {transform.Translate(Vector2.right * walkSpeed); }// RIGHT MOVEMENT

         if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.U)) {
             // Clockwise
             transform.Rotate(0, 0, -3.0f);
         }
         if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.O)) {
             // Counter-clockwise
             transform.Rotate(0, 0, 3.0f); 


         }
     }             
 }
```

If anyone could show me where i'm going wrong that would be lovely. :)

Comment: A very helpful fella on the unity forums clocked onto the answer.           "I can't tell without the script that spawns the missles. However the way you set the direction of the shot in the shot script

     Direction = transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z;
     transform.Rotate(0 , 0, Direction);
     

reads the transformation in the shot script and then rotates the shot even more. This should probably be

     transform.rotation=Shotspawn.rotation;  "

Answer (score 0):

So the reason it doesn't work is because it reads the direction and then adds a bit more to it so it sort of over corrects. So the code should read:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MoveMissile : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization

public float speed = 0.5F;
public Transform Shotspawn;
  void Start (){

   // Sets the direction that shot is fired in.
  transform.rotation=Shotspawn.rotation;
  }

  // Update is called once per frame
  void Update () {


  transform.Translate(Vector2.up * speed);
 }
}
```